# How to programmatically add begin date and end date for the past and future that is having an increment of two weeks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hadoop, hive

> I need to create a hive table with three columns (sprint_name,
>   begin_date, end_date). I have the sprint_name column populated and
>   based on that I want to populate the other two columns on a two weeks
>   increment. So basically, a sprint lasts for two weeks. If hive is not
>   possible, please help me on how to create this in sql server.

```
Sprint_name                   Begin_date    End_date
Sprint 1.1  METADATA FYE20    2/6/2019      2/19/2019  
Sprint 1.2  METADATA FYE20    2/20/2019     3/5/2019   
Sprint 1.3  METADATA FYE20    3/6/2019      3/19/2019 
Sprint 1.4  METADATA FYE20            
Sprint 1.5  METADATA FYE20                           
Sprint 1.6  METADATA FYE20                           
Sprint 1.6  METADATA SALE FYE20                      
Sprint 1.7  METADATA FYE20      
Sprint 2.1  METADATA FYE20
Sprint 2.2  METADATA FYE20
Sprint 2.3  METADATA FYE20
Sprint 2.3  METADATA SALE FYE20
Sprint 2.3  METADATA DOWN FYE20
Sprint 2.4  METADATA FYE20
Sprint 2.5  METADATA FYE20
Sprint 2.6  METADATA FYE20      7/10/2019        7/23/2019
Sprint 2.7  SALE FYE20          7/24/2019        8/6/2019      
Sprint 2.7  METADATA FYE20      7/24/2019        8/6/2019
Sprint 3.1  METADATA FYE20     
.
.
.
Sprint 4.6  METADATA FYE20
.
.
Sprint 1.1  METADATA FYE21
```

Comment: how you will identify the begin date for each individual record? end date can be set for later two weeks

Comment: @vikrantrana the begin date will be the day after the end date

Comment: Can you show some date sample for first record and your expectation for rest of the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one more trick to update the table using CTE with Posexplode in Hive.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.test_date
(
 userid int
,sprint_name string
,start_date date
,end_date date
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS orc
;
```

Insert first record with your start date and end date and leave date as null for rest of the entries.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE db.test_date VALUES
(1,'Sprint 1.1  METADATA FYE20','2019-02-06','2019-02-19' ),
(2,'Sprint 1.2  METADATA FYE20',NULL,NULL),
(3,'Sprint 1.3  METADATA FYE20',NULL,NULL ),
(4,'Sprint 1.4  METADATA FYE20',NULL,NULL),
(5,'Sprint 1.5  METADATA FYE20',NULL,NULL),
(6,'Sprint 1.6  METADATA FYE20',NULL,NULL),
(7,'Sprint 1.6  METADATA SALE ',NULL,NULL),
(8,'Sprint 1.7  METADATA FYE20',NULL,NULL),
(9,'Sprint 2.1  METADATA FYE20',NULL,NULL),
(10,'Sprint 2.2  METADATA FYE20',NULL,NULL);
```

**Query:**

```
with
CTE AS (
select date_add(start_date,((pe.i)* 14)) as start_date,date_add(end_date,((pe.i)*14)) as end_date,pe.i+1 as userid
from  db.test_date 
lateral view 
posexplode(split(space(10-1),' ')) pe as i,x
where start_date is not null
)
insert overwrite table db.test_date
select 
 t.Userid
,t.sprint_name
,d.start_date
,d.end_date
FROM db.test_date t
CROSS JOIN CTE d
on d.userid=t.userid
```

;

**Note:** I thought of using posexplode(split(space(max(userid)-min(userid),' ')) pe as i,x
but max & min has not support for UDAF.

**results:**

```
hive> select * from db.test_date;
OK
1       Sprint 1.1  METADATA FYE20      2019-02-06      2019-02-19
2       Sprint 1.2  METADATA FYE20      2019-02-20      2019-03-05
3       Sprint 1.3  METADATA FYE20      2019-03-06      2019-03-19
4       Sprint 1.4  METADATA FYE20      2019-03-20      2019-04-02
5       Sprint 1.5  METADATA FYE20      2019-04-03      2019-04-16
6       Sprint 1.6  METADATA FYE20      2019-04-17      2019-04-30
7       Sprint 1.6  METADATA SALE       2019-05-01      2019-05-14
8       Sprint 1.7  METADATA FYE20      2019-05-15      2019-05-28
9       Sprint 2.1  METADATA FYE20      2019-05-29      2019-06-11
10      Sprint 2.2  METADATA FYE20      2019-06-12      2019-06-25
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL-Server, assuming you have `begin_date` and `end_date` values for the first record, 
you can use window function to update the date values for next rows.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
Id Int Identity(1,1),Sprint_name varchar(max),Begin_date date, end_date date
)
INSERT INTO Table1 Values
('Sprint 1.1  METADATA FYE20'  ,  '2/6/2019'  ,    '2/19/2019' )
,('Sprint 1.2 METADATA FYE20' , NULL, NULL)
,('Sprint 1.3  METADATA FYE20',NULL,NULL)--insert all sprint_name values and NULL in begin_Date,end_date columns


;with cte as(
select 
 Id,
sprint_name,
ISNULL(dateadd(day,((id-1)*14),first_value(begin_Date) over (order by id rows unbounded preceding)),begin_date) as begin_date,
ISNULL(dateadd(day,((id-1)*14),first_value(end_date) over (order by id rows unbounded preceding)),end_date) as end_date
from Table1 
)
update T
set T.Begin_Date=C.Begin_Date,
T.End_Date = C.End_Date
from Table1 T
inner join CTE C
on C.Id = T.Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding below answer if you want to do it in Hive.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_dev_db.test_date
(
Userid int
,sprint_name string
,start_date date
,end_date date
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS orc
;
```

Loading just four records as a sample, you can load all the records.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE test_dev_db.test_date VALUES
(1,'Sprint 1.1','2019-02-06','2019-02-19' ),
(2,'Sprint 1.2',NULL,NULL),
(3,'Sprint 1.3',NULL,NULL ),
(4,'Sprint 1.4',NULL,NULL);


with date_range as(
select 
Userid
,sprint_name
,date_add(first_value(start_date) over (order by Userid rows unbounded preceding),((Userid-1)*14)) as start_date
,date_add(first_value(end_date) over (order by Userid rows unbounded preceding),((Userid-1)*14)) as end_date
from test_dev_db.test_date
)
insert overwrite table test_dev_db.test_date
select date_range.Userid,date_range.sprint_name
,date_range.start_date
,date_range.end_date from date_range;


hive> select * from test_dev_db.test_date;
OK
1       Sprint 1.1      2019-02-06      2019-02-19
2       Sprint 1.2      2019-02-20      2019-03-05
3       Sprint 1.3      2019-03-06      2019-03-19
4       Sprint 1.4      2019-03-20      2019-04-02
Time taken: 0.206 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```